# Push and Pull in Foundation Grid

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I need a layout in foundation that on medium and above is:

```
[8][4A]
   [4B]
```

And on small:

```
[4A]
[8]
[4B]
```

I'm close to achieving this, but when I have lots of content in my 8 block, 4B is pushed down the page, I need it to site right below 4A

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjYGLa)

Answer (score 0):

Can you stack them in this order or it will conflic with your template ? Seems to fix the gap

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="small-12 columns medium-4 medium-push-8 ">
     <div class="panel">        4A</div>
     <div class="panel">        4B</div>
  </div>

 <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-pull-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

If you want `4b` to be below the `column medium-8` then add a `.clearfix` after it

```
  <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-pull-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
         <p>Content</p>
         <p>Content</p>
        </div>
  </div>

   <div class="clearfix"></div> // here clear floating position

 <div class="small-12 columns medium-4 medium ">
    <div class="panel">4A</div>      
 </div>
```

Comment: Fixes the gap but does not adhere to my requirements on mobile - 4B needs to go below 8.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but your edit does not appear to work either - where has 4B gone?

Comment: it will be positioned below the content div [8] because [8] is floating left and [4a] right but [4b] is not

Comment: Thanks for the pen, this no longer works on medium now.